# Having problems trying to test functionality that contains autowired SprngBoot with junit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to test some functinality, a service with a repo that is autowired in. I dont want to mock the autowired, this is more a integration test for debugging.

My test is as follow

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ThrottleRateServiceTest {
    
    ThrottleRateService service = null;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        service = new ThrottleRateServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testThrottoling() {
        service.isAllowed("test");
    }
}
```

The code is very simple

```
@Service
public class ThrottleRateServiceImpl implements ThrottleRateService {
    
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ThrottleRateServiceImpl.class);
    
    @Autowired
    ThrottleRateRepository throttleRateRepository;
```

The problem is that throttleRateRepository is always null.

I have managed to test this sort of code before. With Junit 4  with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Which autowired all the beans.
Its been a while since I did this sort of integration testing, and its all changed with Junit 5.
Thanks or any hep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in that code:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    service = new ThrottleRateServiceImpl();
}
```

You shouldn't create beans manually. In this case Spring cannot manage it and autowire repository.

> If you need to recreate your service before each method call, you can use class annotation `@DirtiesContext(methodMode = MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)`. You can read about it more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext).

Instead of this, autowire `ThrottleRateServiceImpl` like the repository. Also, for the correct autowiring, you may need to have a test configuration. It could be inner static class, or a separate class.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ThrottleRateServiceTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public ThrottleRateService throttleRateService() {
            return new ThrottleRateServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    ThrottleRateService service;

    @Test
    public void testThrottoling() {
        service.isAllowed("test");
    }
}
```

You can read more about initializing beans for testing and test configurations in [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-init-a-bean-for-testing/).

Also, very helpful [an official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications):

> If you are using JUnit 4, do not forget to also add
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations
> will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there is no need to add the
> equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and
> the other @…​Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Comment: Thank you for replying I did try @Autowired
 ThrottleRateService service;  But then got the error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.opsec.shared.harvesting.fetcher.throttling.service.ThrottleRateService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.  I cant even autowire in the test itself. I dont really want to go back to junit 4. But it seems that that junit 5 is really falling down on this.

Comment: In this case you need to add your own test configuration. I will update my answer with it.

Comment: Fixed it, just neededc@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, what I did was replace
@SpringBootTest with  @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

And autowired the ThrottleRateService

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ThrottleRateServiceTest {
    
    
    @Autowired
    ThrottleRateService service;

    @Test
    public void testThrottoling() {
        service.isAllowed("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).